# How to save gt table as svg

Tags: r, svg, gt

I have created a gt table using mt cars. I can save this table in png, pdf, html, rtf, ltx, tex formats. But, is there a way to save the table in svg format?

Comment: Can you provide the code to generate such `gt` table? That would help those who are unfamiliar with the `gt` package notice if there's any peculiar detail about it that would affect your desired answer. About your problem, I believe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287652/how-to-save-a-table-i-created-with-dt-datatable-into-a-high-quality-image this should help.

Comment: The documentation for `gtsave` specifies `either an HTML, PDF, PNG, LaTeX, or RTF file`, so I would guess that svg is not supported